# Using a MS SQL Connector, how do you insert utcnow() into a datetime field?

Tags: azure-logic-apps, workflow-definition-language

utcnow() is one of the functions supported by logic apps.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/azure/dn948512.aspx#functions

I've tried using it in conjunction with an insert action from a SQL Connector to insert data into a table.  The table has a datetime field that I'd like to populate with the date/time that the workflow performs the insert.  I've tried the following:

1. `{@utcnow()}` which results in the following error:

`"Error reading date. Unexpected token: StartObject. Path '', line 1, position 1."`

and this:

2. `@utcnow()` which results in the following error:

`"Error reading date. Unexpected token: Integer. Path '', line 1, position 1."`

I'm hoping this is a silly formatting issue, because I'm not very familiar with logic apps' workflow definition language.

Thanks!

Comment: I've tried the "o", "s" and "u" formatters as parameters to the utcnow() function, with similar results.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SQL connector` got some new fixes related to `Datetime`. Now, no need to provide any quotes and it supports the date time of `ISO 8601` `(Round trip 'O)`.

Examples are : `2015-06-01 19:15:45.000, 6/1/2015 7:15:45 PM` or `@utcnow()`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: While @photohunts' answer was correct... it seems it no longer works and @{utcnow()} does work.

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work with

```
'@{utcnow('s')}'
```

The @ sign needs to be outside of the {}. I am not entirely sure the outer single quotes are necessary, but I was getting errors at the time without them. Hope that helps.

Comment: Ahh, the outer 's made the difference.  I should have caught this too because I had the same issue with guid() earlier, but got it working by putting 's around it.  Thanks again!